# Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter throws jakarta.xml.bind.MarshalException: null at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jaxb, glassfish, glassfish-3

While marshalling the object with Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter I am getting below exception. I am not sure why this exception is coming. There is nothing wrong with the Object which it's trying to convert. Sometime for the same object it is able to convert but sometime it throw exception. I have already checked dependency version(Picking from latest one).

````
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "chars" is null
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.characters(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:463)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:243)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:229)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:229)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:229)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:229)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:229)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:229)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:92)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:718)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:780)
    ... 168 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "chars" is null
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:789)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.writeDom(XMLSerializer.java:764)
    ... 166 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "chars" is null
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:226)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.writeDom(XMLSerializer.java:766)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:556)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:314)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:265)
    ... 146 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: jakarta.xml.bind.MarshalException: null
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:197)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:925)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:593)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)```


* Already tried version update and checked if concurrency issue.
````